# Get Locations of Post For Directory Map

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, loops

I have php knowledge and wordpress but i'm not good at JavaScript. I'm trying to do a directory wordpress theme but. I need to get locations of posts in the loop like archive or category for map.

My page showing posts like this (lat, lng and title values comes with php i dont have a problem there);

```
<div class="loop">
    <article class="post" lat="23.453256" lng="25.453245" title="Post Title">
      <!--loop content.-->
    </article>
    <article class="post" lat="23.653256" lng="25.153245" title="Post Title">
      <!--loop content.-->
    </article>
    <article class="post" lat="23.253256" lng="25.953245" title="Post Title">
      <!--loop content.-->
    </article>
</div>
```

But i have javascript for google map in page but i need to write in javascript like that :

```
var locations = [
  ['Post Title 1',23.453256,25.453245, 1],
  ['Post Title 2',23.653256,25.153245, 1],
  ['Post Title 3',23.253256,25.953245, 1],
];
```

how can i do this?

Comment: For me it is not very clear what you trying to archive. Your page generates the articles as above, right? And you just don´t know how to access these values now, or what?

Comment: Are you creating the HTML in your example using PHP in a loop? You can do the same to create the JavaScript

Comment: Shortly wordpress create loop like first code, and i want this posts lat,lng and title values and use it in my map code like second code box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery you can do check my below code, For your understanding i have made it very simple.

I have used your jQuery class selector to get all your posts based on your class name.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var location = new Array();
    $('.post').each(function() {
        lat = $(this).attr('lat');
        lng = $(this).attr('lng');
        title = $(this).attr('title');
        post = new Array(title, lat, lng, 1);
        Posts.push(location);
    });                
    console.log(location);
});
```

You can use your location variable to plot the marker on your map.
Refer google api : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

Comment: Yes it gets values fine but, i'm very bad in javascript :D can you tell me how can i write this to my map codes like my example

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: i already write it up in my question manually as google's documentation.Its working already if i write values manually but it is dynamic page and i need to get info and write this automatically from those attributes like echo $lat. as php.

Comment: Pls update your code you have used for google maps in your question